# Getting the command run which returned piped input

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x

I have this Python 3 code stored in `pipe.py`, which accepts some piped input and prints it line-by-line:

```
import sys

for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    print("{}: {}".format(i, line))
```

I can then run this in Bash:

```
$ echo "Test" | python pipe.py
0: Test
```

This is working as intended, but what I'm interested in is if there is a way to actually get the command run which resulted in the piped input. So, for my example above, the value `Test` was piped into the program, but `echo "Test"` was executed to get this value.

Is there a way I can get that `echo "Test"` command as a string in my Python program?

Comment: Std in could be a file or a whole pipeline of commands, or just a terminal, so in general there is no such thing as a "command" you could get.

Comment: It's useful to determine if `sys.stdin` is attached to an on-disk file or a pipe, but probably less necessary to know the actual command on the other end of a pipe.

Comment: @chepner Is there a way to find out where `sys.stdin` came from?

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 you can tell that is is from a pipe by looking at `sys.stdin.isatty()` which will be `False` when it's a pipe, but I don't know how to find what's on the other end, or even how many things are on the other end as antlersoft mentioned.  What would you want if there was a string of 5 commands before your script?

Comment: As a bit of an aside, why reimplement `nl` (or alternatively, `cat -n`)?

Comment: maybe this helps http://serverfault.com/questions/48330/how-can-i-get-more-info-on-open-pipes-show-in-proc-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible -- at least on Linux when you have the `/proc` filesystem, *and* if a) your stdin is a pipe at all and b) the pipe sender isn't gone yet.

The idea is to **check the `/proc` filesystem for corresponding pipe entries**:

- Your Python script has the pipe connected to stdin (file descriptor 0).
- The other end of the pipe is connected to the stdout file descriptor (1) of the sending process.

As an example, assuming that your Python script has process id 1001 and the sender has pid 1000, this is what you'd see:

```
$ ls -l /proc/1001/fd/0
lr-x------ 1 user users 64 Sep 22 14:41 /proc/1001/fd/0 -> 'pipe:[507536]'

$ ls -l /proc/1000/fd/1
l-wx------ 1 user users 64 Sep 22 14:41 /proc/1000/fd/1 -> 'pipe:[507536]'
```

So with a little search in `/proc`, you can get what you want. **Here's an example in `bash` that does what you want** -- the output is

```
$ yes 1 2  | ./find-piper.sh 
sender pid is 21380, command is "yes 1 2 "
```

The `find-piper.sh` script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

myPid=$$

# determine pipe connected to stdin:
myPipeNumber=$( readlink /proc/$myPid/fd/0 | sed -n 's,^pipe:\[\([0-9]\+\)\]$,\1,;T;p' )
if [[ -z $myPipeNumber ]] ; then
  echo "input is not a pipe"
else
  # find process with stdout connected to our pipe
  senderPipe=$( find /proc -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -path "*/fd/1" -lname "pipe:\[$myPipeNumber\]" 2>/dev/null )
  senderPid=$( sed -n 's,/proc/\([0-9]\+\)/.*,\1,;T;p' <<< "$senderPipe" )

  # report pid and command line of sender
  if [[ -z $senderPid ]] ; then
    echo "could not find sender pid"
  else
    echo "sender pid is $senderPid, command is \"$( tr '\000' ' ' </proc/$senderPid/cmdline )\""
  fi
fi

# eat input
cat > /dev/null
```

Conversion to Python is left as an exercise : )

**Caveats**:

- The second precondition ("the pipe sender isn't gone yet") will, however, not be given in your case, as `echo "Test"` will complete extremely fast.
- If your sender pipe consists of several commands (like, `(echo "Test"; sleep 2) | python pipe.py`) then you'll find multiple sender entries.

Comment: Looks interesting! I'll take a closer look later.